# Can I procedurally export ESmodules using destructuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, ecmascript-2016

I have a file that default exports an object containing constants.  I'd also like to export each of the properties of the object.  Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve writing them all out?

```
import keyMirror from 'keymirror';

// keymirror outputs an object with key = val.  eg. {a: a, b: b, ...}
const types = keyMirror({
  FREEFORM: null,
  GRAPH_IMAGE: null,
  ...
});

export default types;

export const FREEFORM = types.FREEFORM;
export const GRAPH_IMAGE = types.GRAPH_IMAGE;
...
```

Comment: ES6 exports need to be able to know the names of exports before the file has been executed, so they will need to be enumerated explicitly somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `export`, though you can use a single destructuring assignment

```
const {FREEFORM, GRAPH_IMAGE, ..} = types;
```